# asp.net core 2 multiple web.config files (different environments)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This issue is not related to application configurations (custom), but more to do with IIS settings.

So I need the following to be in the web.config when i create a publish for my app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

However, when debugging i only want the  part and not the http redirect (If i try to debug my app with the rewrite in the web.config it does not start)

in previous asp.net, we could have multiple web.configs for debug and release and it would transform when published.

I simply want to the all of the above code to be in the web.config when published, and only  part to be in applied in web.config when i am debugging

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a true answer to your question, but I've got what I think is a much better solution overall. For some time, I've found the fact that URL Rewrites have to go into the Web.config to be frustrating. As careful as you are, it's almost inevitable that you're going to overwrite the Web.config at some point, removing rewrites that have been added to it. This is especially the case if a developer doesn't know better and adds a rewrite directly through IIS, but never copies it over to the project's Web.config in source control (which happens more often than not).

As a result, I started creating a site in IIS just for redirects like this. It has nothing but a Web.config, and then I add the bindings that I'm redirecting from to it. For example, for a rewrite like this, you'd add the binding for the HTTP version of your domain to the redirect site and the HTTPS binding to the actual web application site. Then, you can create the rewrite rule on the the redirect "site", and never ever worry about accidentally overwriting it, because you never publish anything there. This would effectively side-step your issue here, entirely.

Comment: I initially had it done on the IIS, then i did a deployment (i think it was cus of deployment) then my rule in IIS disappeared, so i assumed it was because my site web.config was overriding IIS, but yes I agree rewriting the rules in IIS is a much better solution.

Comment: That was my point. The key is to move the rewrite out of your application's web.config and into a web.config that never changes. You can create a simple site in IIS that maps to a folder with only a Web.config. Then, you can just add all your rewrite rules there and never worry about accidentally clobbering one during deployment.

Comment: Granted, that only works if it's a domain/protocol the web application should never use. It still doesn't solve some more specific rewrite issues like redirecting from one page to another within the same site. However, for all the "redirect HTTP to HTTPS", "redirect non-www to www", etc. rules, it works great.